# How to configure Notification in iOS10 (same as Android using GCM ID)?

Tags: push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect, ios10

I want to configure the Notification in Swift 3(ios 10). I want it similar to Android system, is it Possible?? without .pem file is it possible to send remote notification in ios10.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without .pem file.

You can use Pushok is a simple PHP library for sending push notifications to APNs.

https://github.com/edamov/pushok

Comment: example in laravel ?

Comment: Laravel is with php as I know. You can use this sendpush.php file, but yes there is pem file confuguration, you can use for both push notification and silent push notification https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

*Without .pem(Apple Developer Certificate) not possible to send push notification*

Comment: yes it is possible @ronak go through link  http://gobiko.com/blog/token-based-authentication-http2-example-apns/

Comment: Ok sorry I don't know new feature added by apple developer account